# Twitter-like "follow user" and "watch this" problem

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, many-to-many

What's the best way to handle many-to-many trigger relationships like the Twitter "follow this user" problem.

I have a similar problem with users "watching" threads for replies.  If there are 10,000 users watching a thread, and someone replies, how best to notify the watchers?  All I can think of is the following:

Upon insert, check the "watch table" [fields: user_id, thread_id] for any thread matching this thread's id.  This is the list of users I need to notify.  For each user that needs to be notified, insert a row into the "notification table" [fields: user_id, message, addedon, etc].  Now I can show any user their notifications via this table.

Problem is, this all sounds very, very expensive.  Especially the 10,000 inserts part.

There must be a better way to do this...  ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In your watch table you could add a `last_updated` field and set that when the watched thread is updated.  Also add a field for `last_notified`, set this when you notify the user, you will know you need to notify the user if `last_updated > last_notified`.  When you decide that you need to notify the user just show them all messages from the thread with a `post_date >= last_updated`.

Comment: Damn, was writing the same idea :)

Comment: So there is no "notifications" table.. instead I check on a user-by-user basis?

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to notify a user on some event, such as when they login to a web interface or request it through a REST service.  You would just check all of the specific user's watch entries when they need to be notified.